# How to combine 2 not even cells into 1 cell in MAtlab?

Tags: matlab, cell

I got a problem here. I want read an excel file (Test.xls) with 2 sheets (test 1 & test 2) in matlab and use its data to analyze. So I did: 
              [a,b,c]=xlsread('Test.xls', 'text 1');
and           [d,e,f]=xlsread('Test.xls', 'text 2');

The result that I got:
       c is: <65000x18 cell>
and    f is: <24912x18 cell>

Can anyone help me to join these 2 cell into 1? As
       z is: <89912x18 cell>
or either way is to read all 2 sheets into the 'z'

Thanks a lot in advance

Jacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to transpose each then transpose the result.

```
z = [ c' f']'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippe. That is exactly what I want. Regards. Jacky

Comment: Two things: as "AlwaysWrong" suggests, vertical concatenation is better here. Also, you're using the complex-conjugate transpose twice here.

Comment: @Edric yeah you could do that.

Answer (score 6):

You could also concatenate them vertically to start using:

```
z = [c;f];
```